# Left Join Not Joining with a Single Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have the following query:

```
Insert into cet_database.dbo.termData
    (
        termID,
        studentID,
        course,
        [current],
        program,
        StbyCurrentClassID,
        class,
        classCode,
        cancelled
    )
    Select
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.termID,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.class_code,
        case when fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.[current] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.program,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.classByStudentID,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.class,
        fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.classID,
        case when fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.cancelled_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end
From fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData left outer join termData
    On fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.class_code = termData.course
    and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.termID = termData.termID
    and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID = fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID
Where termData.StbyCurrentClassID is null
```

I use the query to import data into a staging table from another database (`fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData`) before importing it into my database's tables. This particular query is part of a larger stored procedure that imports data into multiple tables related to `termData`.

When I run the sproc, I get the record inserted into `fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData` but not into `termData`. I am only inserting one record when having this problem, but it works for the 10,000 records I did previously. I use the left join to establish what already exists in my database's table and what doesn't, then take the relevant records from the staging table. However, with this record:

```
316a, 39520, DEC 10, Yes, DEC10, 105713, DEC 10 (18), 6078, NULL, 2
```

The select returns nothing - why is this? The record definitely doesn't exist in my `termData` table and records insert into all my other tables from the staging table. The sproc is running all of the inserts in a transaction so as to avoid precisely this scenario where records are inserted in some tables and not others, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Well, the only reason for not getting the record should be the `WHERE` clause. Remove it and run the altered select query to see what you unexpectedly get.

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle that reproduces the issue?   I don't see anything wrong with the query.

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried creating it in SQL Fiddle (which I haven't used before) but cannot for the life of me get it to do anything e.g. create a table. EDIT: it doesn't seem to work in Firefox...will create a demo.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 
 
If I take away the where clause, I get 666 identical records.

Comment: Okay, and I am sure the records you see have a termID and class_code that is already in the table, so the records don't get inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the query worked for the previous 10,000 records, but doesn't for the current one. The only thing that looks strange in your query is the third line in your `ON` clause where you compare a field (the `studentID`) with itself.

```
On fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.class_code = termData.course
and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.termID = termData.termID
and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID = fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID
```

I am just guessing here, but as this line *is* in the `ON` clause, did you want to compare the student ID, too? So it may be you were just lucky the query worked so far and now you stumble upon the student ID. I suppose the `ON` clause should look like this:

```
On fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.class_code = termData.course
and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.termID = termData.termID
and fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData.studentID = termData.studentID
```

By the way, queries get more readable by using table aliases. In the following query I use `ad` for `fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData` and `td` for `termData`:

```
Insert into cet_database.dbo.termData
(
  termID,
  studentID,
  course,
  [current],
  program,
  StbyCurrentClassID,
  class,
  classCode,
  cancelled
)
Select
  ad.termID,
  ad.studentID,
  ad.class_code,
  case when ad.[current] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end,
  ad.program,
  ad.classByStudentID,
  ad.class,
  ad.classID,
  case when ad.cancelled_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end
From fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData ad
Left Outer Join termData td On  ad.class_code = td.course
                            And ad.termID     = td.termID
                            And ad.studentID  = td.studentID
Where td.StbyCurrentClassID is null;
```

Moreover when checking for existence, why do you use the anti-join trick? Did you have issues with a straight-forward `NOT EXISTS`? Use tricks only when really needed. The query reads better as follows:

```
Insert into cet_database.dbo.termData
(
  termID,
  studentID,
  course,
  [current],
  program,
  StbyCurrentClassID,
  class,
  classCode,
  cancelled
)
  Select
    termID,
    studentID,
    class_code,
    case when [current] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end,
    program,
    classByStudentID,
    class,
    classID,
    case when cancelled_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end
  From fm_stg.classByStudent_termData_assessmentData ad
  Where Not Exists
  (
     Select *
     From termData td 
     Where ad.class_code = td.course
       And ad.termID     = td.termID
       And ad.studentID  = td.studentID
);
```

With another DBMS you could even have used `NOT IN` (i.e. `Where (class_code, termId, studenId) Not In (Select ...)`) which is not correlated so such a typo as yours could not even have occurred, but SQL Server doesn't feature tuples in the `IN` clause unfortunately.

Comment: I use the 'anti-join' trick for no particularly good reason, other than familiarity - thanks for suggesting something else. I presume the performance of `Not Exists` is better? I think the issue I had was that the record inserted into a whole lot of related tables, but not into the `termData` table. I still don't really understand why this is from my sproc, but if I delete all the records in the related tables, it seems to work. This broke in the first place because of a bad record from my source (a linked server/database that isn't mine). Thanks for your help.